# Observe changes to a nested array doesn't return element added/changed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am using an `observeChanges` on this cursor as follows. The cursor contains a nested array called "messages".

```
Connections.find({
  status: 'connected'
}).observeChanges({
  added: function (id) {
    console.log(`Connected ${id}`);
  },
  changed: function (id, fields) {
    // I expect fields to be the last array item pushed
    console.log(fields['messages']);
  }
});
```

However, this yields all the messages, rather than the ones changed or added. How can you just get the last ones pushed? Getting the *last* one won't work as intended because you can push multiple at a time.

[Here is a fully working example on meteorpad if you want to see what I mean in action (look at console.logs)](http://meteorpad.com/pad/fyAepn2FYojHKhBjL/Leaderboard)

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable the observeChanges during the first step to only catch new things:

```
var init = true;
Connections.find({
  status: 'connected'
}).observeChanges({
  added: function (id) {
    if(init) return;
    console.log(`Connected ${id}`);
  },
  changed: function (id, fields) {
    if(init) return;
    // I expect fields to be the last array item pushed
    console.log(fields['messages']);
  }
});
init = false;
```

here is the meteorpad version:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/2NcJwxHYQNTqktMa5/Copy%20of%20Leaderboard

Comment: I've added an example. I do not believe that this works as intended

Comment: i changed the answer, it should do what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do it, it's just not using `observeChanges`, uses `observe` instead.

```
Connections.find({
  status: 'connected'
}).observe({
  changed: function (newDoc, oldDoc) {
    let newMessages = _.clone(newDoc.messages);
    let old = _.clone(oldDoc.messages);
    while (JSON.stringify(old) !== JSON.stringify(newMessages.slice(0, old.length))) {
      old.shift();
    }
    let last = newMessages.slice(old.length);
  }
});
```

Comment: Just wondering if you had perfomance issues in the meanwhile when your collection size increased.